# Select product having more than one color?

Tags: sql, select, join, normalization

I have two table product and product colors

For example

**Products**

```
id   name
1    T Shirt 
2    Jeans
3    Coat
```

**Product Colors**

```
id   color     p_id
1    Green     1
2    red       1
3    yellow    1
```

T Shirt have 3 colors Green, Red, Yellow.

Now i want to select product name which have green, red, yellow colors

**Note**

In Query returns me all products which have red color, Green color, Yellow color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get products having all three colors you can do

```
select p.name
from products p
join productColors pc on pc.p_id = p.id
where pc.color in ('green','red','yellow')
group by p.id, p.name
having count(distinct pc.id) = 3
```

Comment: now i have one more problem i have product having red,green,purple color it have 3 colors and red and green is there. It should not return image having purple color. Can you help me with this?

Comment: The query above should work. Using the `where` clause you can specify the colors you are looking for and in the `having` clause you add the number of colors you filter in the `where` clause